# How to add title on top of Post title in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add a title attached to a URL on top of titles on all posts. How can I achieve it using using CSS or Jquery?

To be specific refer to the image below.

https://i.imgur.com/qKPwrvZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I managed to do it.

1. I located the template part for single posts (single.php). This is the template that's responsible for all the content formatting on your posts.
2. I located where the entry title (post title) is positioned.
3. I created a div class of the title that I want to add on the post title (entry title).
4. I added a link to the new title that I have created. So it looks like this
5. The reason for creating a div class is to enable me to add CSS to the class without interfering with the entry-title class.
6. Now I added CSS and it looks perfect the way  I wanted

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve with multiple ways,

1. You can install plugin ACF add post meta field to every post
2. Open index.php in your theme files or open your template file where you fetch all posts.

   **

   Ensure you paste the code in an appropriate position in the file, ensuring it’s pasted after this line:

   ```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    And before:

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    Use the following snipped to embed the metadata, changing the class name, field name and HTML formatting as required.

    <p class="myfieldname"><?php the_field('Field_Name'); ?></p>

    Save the file, and head to your site’s front-end to review.
   ```

**

Comment: Can you break it down a bit? You have mixed both the code with the explanation.